# How to declare typescript type to guarantee it's an assignable subset of another type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to declare a merge function that will assign all the fields of one value to another value but I'm having trouble properly defining the types of the `merge` function. I can never get all the test case to pass.

```
interface Person {
  Name: string;
  Age: number;
  Occupation?: string;
}

// Tried
const merge = <T>(full: T, partial: Partial<T>): T => ({ ...full, ...partial });

// Also Tried
const merge = <T, U>(full: T extends U, partial: U): T => ({ ...full, ...partial });

const human: Person = {
  Name: "John",
  Age: 35,
};

// Expected results:
merge(human, { Age: 5 });                  // ✓
merge(human, { Name: "Marc" });            // ✓
merge(human, { Name: undefined });         //  Person.Name cannot be undefined.
merge(human, { Occupation: "Fishermen" }); // ✓
merge(human, { Occupation: undefined });   // ✓
merge(human, { Beer: 5 });                 //  Person.Beer does not exists.
```

Comment: Ugh, I was gonna say, turn on [exactOptionalPropertyTypes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes), but it throws still for line 23 (which is correct and I understand why it shouldn't) - https://tsplay.dev/NB5opw

Comment: Ok, I still think you should turn on exactOptionalPropertyTypes, but then you can define a type like "LoosePartial", which checks if `undefined` is allowed for that key and preserves it: https://tsplay.dev/mbQo4N

Comment: Unfortunately my project is stuck in 4.0 because of angular 10. But I'll write down notes to turn it on when we upgrade. If you have a answer I'll approve it it's perfect.

Comment: No problem, you can still make it work: https://tsplay.dev/m360jN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TS 4.4, `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` was introduced, which makes sure optional properties don't necessarily accept `undefined` anymore. This makes the solution really simple with `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` enabled:

```
type LoosePartial<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: undefined extends T[K] ? T[K] | undefined : T[K];
};

const merge = <T>(full: T, partial: LoosePartial<T>): T => ({ ...full, ...partial });
```

All we have to do is first check if `undefined` is assignable to `T[K]`, and if it is, we "preserve" `undefined` in the mapping. Otherwise, we use `T[K]` by itself as the type.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbQo4N)

---

In TS 4.3 and older, this is still possible, but it looks a little crazier, due to the checks that you now have to manually add in:

```
const merge = <T, U>(full: T, partial: {
  [K in keyof U]:
  K extends keyof Person
    ? undefined extends Person[K]
      ? U[K] // If undefined is allowed, we don't care
      : undefined extends U[K] // If it isn't, and undefined was given, we care
        ? never
        : U[K]
    : never; // Key doesn't even exist in Person
}): T => ({ ...full, ...partial });
```

This also works in TS 4.4 in case you don't want to enable `exactOptionalPropertyTypes`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m360jN)

You could also move the mapped type into a type alias to keep it clean:

```
type ArtificialLoosePartial<U> = {
  [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof Person ? undefined extends Person[K] ? U[K] : undefined extends U[K] ? never : U[K] : never;
};

const merge = <T, U>(full: T, partial: ArtificialLoosePartial<U>): T => ({ ...full, ...partial });
```

Comment: Oh I even get the pre 4.4 version. What a boss.